# Receiving strings on Arduino - problems -

Tags: string, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a problem with my code when I receive a string from my app in Android.
I need to send some string from my App to Arduino (over bluetooth BLE), and get data in a SdCard (in Arduino).
The strings are two and the first string that I need to send is:

```
U\n
```

and the last one is:

```
0 20/11/25 18:18:46\n
```

The code in Arduino for process this strings is:

```
SoftwareSerial HM10(8, 9);            
char appData = ' ';
String inData = "";

void loop() {
      HM10.listen();  // listen the HM10 port
      while (HM10.available() > 0){
        appData = HM10.read();
        delay(50);
        inData = inData+appData;
        if (appData == '\n'){
          Serial.print("String:");
          Serial.println(inData);
          R_SdCard(inData);
          inData="";
        }
      }
    }
```

Ok, the output for *Serial.print("String:");* print **U** (the result that I expect), but when I need to send the last one string I only receive trash...
But if I forward the last string again, now the string received it's Ok!!
I have also sent the first string (the string received is Ok) and next restart Arduino and finally send the last string and the string received ( the last one) is Ok!!
I tried to understand where is the problem but without results... maybe I need to put in blank to appData??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have a 50ms delay in there? This makes that 20 characters long string take 1 second.

Comment: Hi!  Maybe I could to delete it. I found in a forum that it is helpful to read  the entring strings. Do you think that it is the problem??